# PowerMockito chaining doesn't work reliably for Spied class

Tags: mockito, powermockito

I've a test where the System Under Test calls a static method. The static method belongs to a final class(it is a utility class).
The test code is as follows:

```
@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
  SUT sut = PowerMockito.spy(new SUT());
  PowerMockito.spy(A.class);
  stub(method(A.class, "methodOne")).toReturn("CONST_STRING");
  PowerMockito.when(A.methodTwo(anyLong(), anyLong()))
                .thenReturn(false, true, false); //The problem!
  sut.method("arg1");
  assertThat(//some assert);
}
```

I get intermittent errors on the below line. It passes sometimes & sometimes, it fails.

```
PowerMockito.when(A.methodTwo(anyLong(), anyLong()))
                    .thenReturn(false, true, false);
```

When it fails, below is the error that it displays:

```
[junit] Misplaced argument matcher detected here:
    [junit]
    [junit] -> at com.project.SUTTest.test(SUTTest.java:40)
    [junit] -> at com.project.SUTTest.test(SUTTest.java:40)
    [junit]
    [junit] You cannot use argument matchers outside of verification or stubbing.
    [junit] Examples of correct usage of argument matchers:
    [junit]     when(mock.get(anyInt())).thenReturn(null);
    [junit]     doThrow(new RuntimeException()).when(mock).someVoidMethod(anyObject());
    [junit]     verify(mock).someMethod(contains("foo"))
    [junit]
    [junit] Also, this error might show up because you use argument matchers with methods that cannot be mocked.
    [junit] Following methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified: final/private/equals()/hashCode().
    [junit] Mocking methods declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.
    [junit]
    [junit] org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException:
    [junit] Misplaced argument matcher detected here:
    [junit]
    [junit] -> at com.project.SUTTest.test(SUTTest.java:40)
    [junit] -> at com.project.SUTTest.test(SUTTest.java:40)
    [junit]
    [junit] You cannot use argument matchers outside of verification or stubbing.
    [junit] Examples of correct usage of argument matchers:
    [junit]     when(mock.get(anyInt())).thenReturn(null);
    [junit]     doThrow(new RuntimeException()).when(mock).someVoidMethod(anyObject());
    [junit]     verify(mock).someMethod(contains("foo"))
    [junit]
    [junit] Also, this error might show up because you use argument matchers with methods that cannot be mocked.
    [junit] Following methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified: final/private/equals()/hashCode().
    [junit] Mocking methods declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.
```

My version of PowerMockito - 1.6.3
What is happening? Why is the failure intermittent? What is causing this unreliable behaviour?

PowerMockito chaining doesn't work reliably for Spied class

Comment: decouple your code from static dependencies. encapsulate that static resource behind an abstraction and explicitly inject it into the SUT. Just because powermockito allows mocking static does not mean that we should.

Comment: I agree! But, I'm also very curious to know why it fails inconsistently! What is causing the test to succeed sometimes & fail other times.

Comment: If this test is running with other tests it is possible that it may be experiencing a race condition depending on the order of test invocation or resource availability.

Comment: That makes sense. Is there some document/issue that I can read on this?